# WPF how to create tab items

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, tabcontrol

The number of tab items are not predetermined. I just want to create new tab items and then add new rectangles inside current items.
I am generating new tab items(bellow is code) but how can I add rectangles in current tab?

```
var _FloorName = (from fn in db.floors select fn.floorname).ToList();

if (_FloorName.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _FloorName.Count; i++)
    {
        tabControl1.Items.Add(_FloorName[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: "add new rectangles inside current items" ? Do you mean to draw a rectangle inside every single Tab?

Comment: In WPF, you should only create visuals in code if you have exhausted all other alternatives.  See akjoshi's answer.

Comment: @Robert: I fully agree with this sentiment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach you could take:

- Add a [`Grid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) (or other container) to each `TabItem` when creating them
- Create a [`Rectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle.aspx), with the brush/dimensions you want
- Call `tabControl1.SelectedContent`, cast it to `Grid` (or your container type)
- Call `grid.Children.Add(rectangle)`

Here is a complete code sample (using copious code-behind).

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel Margin="12">
        <TabControl Name="tabControl1" Height="250" />
        <Button Content="Add Rectangle" Click="Button_Click"
                Width="90" Height="25" Margin="5" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

public class Floor
{
    public Floor(string name = null)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class FakeDb
{
    public IEnumerable<Floor> Floors
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<Floor>()
            {
                new Floor("floor1"),
                new Floor("floor2"),
                new Floor("floor3"),
            };
        }
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeTabControl();
    }

    private void InitializeTabControl()
    {
        var db = new FakeDb();
        var floorNames = (from fn in db.Floors select fn.Name).ToList();

        foreach (string floorName in floorNames)
        {
            var item = new TabItem()
            {
                Header = floorName,
                Content = new Grid(),
            };
            tabControl1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var rectangle = new Rectangle()
        {
            Stroke = Brushes.Black,
            Fill = Brushes.SkyBlue,
            Width = 50,
            Height = 75,
            Margin = new Thickness(
                left: random.NextDouble() * 300,
                top: random.NextDouble() * 150,
                right: 0,
                bottom: 0),
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
        };
        var grid = (Grid)tabControl1.SelectedContent;
        grid.Children.Add(rectangle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that I like using [the `MVVM` design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel), so I'd actually recommend a completely different approach, but you used code-behind in your question, so I figured I'd stick with it.

Comment: var grid = (Grid)tabControl1.SelectedContent; Thanks but you are adding rectangles in selected tab. I ll try to explain another way. There is room number 1 which is located on first floor and room number 2 lacation is second floor. How i can add room 1 an first floor tab and room 2 on second floor?

Comment: @Acid: You asked "I generating new tab items ... but how i can add rectangles in current tab?"  Are you simply wanting to add rectangles to each tab, while you create them?  This "floors" and "rooms" stuff is really a tangent from your original question.  If you're having problems figuring out your DB schema, you should post another question on SO instead of trying to clarify in these comments - it is totally unrelated to WPF stuff.

Comment: This answer is technically correct - which, as Futurama observes, is the best kind of correct.  But it's not the *right* answer.  Even if you aren't using MVVM per se, you should use data binding and templates to construct WPF visuals.

Comment: @Robert: Lol :)  I keep agreeing with people who say that about my answer.  If you code up an answer that uses it, I'll recommend it be accepted instead.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at this article from Josh Smith -

[Patterns - WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

This is one of the best articles explaining MVVM implementation, the sample application developed creates tabs at runtime and uses templates to display the internal contents. If you can go the same way you will have a very stable and expandable application.

*Note*: Code download available from the [MSDN Code Gallery](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mag200902MVVM)

Comment: No upvote.  This is more a comment than an answer.  It doesn't really solve the problem with the code posted in the question.  However your suggestion is a good one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Merlyn, I provided this answer as you had already provided the obvious solution to the problem; and as you said in your comment using MVVM is the correct approch for implementing this kind of functionality and thats exactly what is done in this sample. For the starter code-behind solution is fine but best solution for this problem is to use MVVM pattern as described in this article.

Comment: @Merlyn: No issues with upvote, my intention is not to accumulate reputation but to share my knowledge and help others. I prefer guiding people in the right direction instead of spoon feeding them, thats how I learned and thats the way I recomment others.

Comment: I guess I missed that code sample link before (somehow?).  Changed my mind on the up-vote.  +1 :)  I still think it would be cool if someone posted code for this particular problem in their answer.

Comment: Thanks Merlyn, I would have loved to do that but its hard to take out some time to create a customized sample.

Answer (score 2):

If this is just adding some control, or draw something on Tab, cause it's not very clear from post, I would personally, strongly recommend to define a **Template** of **TabItem** in **XAML**, as it will **save you a lot of** "drawing fixes" **time**. If yuo have a **Blender** it will become even much easier.

**EDIT**

If you need some sample with binding and whatever, don't have on my hands now the code, but can provide you with a link to open source project. Have look how TabItems are managed there.

[SvnRadar](http://code.google.com/p/svnradar/)

Regards.

Comment: If i know how much tabs and rectangles there would i will do it with blend in xaml. but number of tab items and rectangles are not predetermined.

Comment: @Acid: If you use `DataContext`, combined with data binding on the `ItemsSource` and `Content` properties, then you can still use XAML for drawing, and just provide the drawing *data* in code (a list of rectangle dimension/position data).  This is (basically) the [`MVVM` approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) I was talking about in my comment on my answer.

Comment: @Tigran: Can you provide a code example demonstrating how this can be done with a flexible number of rectangles/tabs?  That would make for a very useful answer (and like you said, probably won't be very hard)

Comment: @Merlyn: can not provide "real" example with XAML, as don't have on my hands now.Should seat and implement some sample. Also cause not very clear what is "Rectangle" ? Can I, for example, just put GroupBox on the control? That is kind of rectangle, or he needs DRAW real rectangle. But at least the collection of Tabs can be definitely pushed on databinding with attached data template.

Comment: @Tigran: There is a `System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle` class that you could use.  That's what I (possibly wrongly) assumed the OP meant.

Comment: The problem with the question that @Acid doesn't specify what he wants, we just "walking arround", by the way I will add some link for  him.