# Tabbed Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, tabs, visual-studio-2019

Does Anyone have a way I can add tabs to my windows form, I am making a browse and i was wanting to make the tabs look like chromes tabs, the modern chrome tabs, not the old ones, iv used easy tabs but I don't really like it with my theme and its not that customizable. is there a visual studio NuGet Package, i also want it where you can click the plus on the top and it will clone my form1 but now show it up as a separate windows in the taskbar

Comment: You will need to use WPF for that. It's actually a really cool way of creating apps. Here is more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/

Comment: OK I created a WPF project I only know C# so that's what I set it to, it is pretty cool it even lets your right HTML at the same time

Comment: I just started playing around with the wpf and i dont know what it means and none of the form settings are the same

Comment: Yes WPF is a big change from forms, you will have to learn it to create tabs and customize it the way you want it. There is a material design toolkit, from there you can create your styles and apply to your project: [Toolkit](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit)

Comment: ok, even if i learn the controls around wpf what do I need to use tabs and get them working properly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759167/wpf-how-to-create-tab-items